# Why is the set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$ not equal to the power set of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Q$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show that $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q}$ is not equal to  $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb {N} \times \Bbb {Q})$.

I think that I would have to show that either $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q} \nsubseteq\mathcal{P}(\Bbb {N} \times \Bbb {Q})$ or that $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q} \nsupseteq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb {N} \times \Bbb {Q})$. But I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Notation-wise, what is $^{\mathbb N}\mathbb Q$?

Comment: I would *guess* that $\;^{\Bbb N}\Bbb Q\;$ is what others (most?) denote as $\;\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}:=\;$ the set of all functions $\;\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q\;$

Comment: @Timbuc: Right.  Some set-theorists prefer this notation because then you can distinguish between, say, $\aleph_0^{\aleph_1}$ (the cardinal number) and ${}^{\aleph_1}\aleph_0$ (the set of functions).

Comment: But then the question is odd: clearly those two sets are no the same, as one is a set of functions and the other one a set of subsets (of $\;\Bbb N\times\Bbb Q\;$ , by the way)...

Comment: Perhaps we shall wait until the OP addresses these doubts...

Comment: Oh, I think I understand: he seems to be taking the functions **already** as subsets of the cartesian product $\;\Bbb N\times\Bbb Q\;$ !

Comment: @Timbuc: That's how the notion of "function" is defined.

Comment: @Frunobulax: Since you're so kin on distinguishing, it should be written $\aleph_0^{\aleph_1}$ is a cardinal number, and ${}^{\omega_1}\omega$ as a set of functions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm not _keen_ on distinguishing, I just tried to explain the notation because AlexR asked.  I'm aware of the convention you mentioned (I co-authored a book about set theory), but it would have made things needlessly complicated.  But I probably should have used something like $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ instead of $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$ above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

${}^{\mathbb N}{\mathbb Q}$ is a subset of ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q})$ because by definition every function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

The other inclusion doesn't hold, though, as for example $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ is an element of the power set, but not a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$.